# Getting a BIT value as to whether a non-Aggregated Value is in a constant list

Tags: t-sql

Given the following tables:

**Logs**

```
-Id
-SuperLogId
-ScanMode
```

**Super Log**

```
-Id
-Name
```

How do I write the following query to get `1` for the Logs from SuperLogs where the Log has a ScanMode of "Navigational", "Locatable" or "Automatic" and `0` otherwise?

```
SELECT Name,
CAST
(
    CASE WHEN
        Logs.ScanMode IN
        (
            'Navigational',
            'Locatable',
            'Automatic'
        )
    THEN
        1
    ELSE
        0
    END
    AS BIT
) HasLogsWithGpsData
FROM SuperLogs
INNER JOIN Logs ON Logs.SuperLogId = SuperLogs.Id
GROUP BY SuperLogs.Id
```

The above query just gives me this error instead of working:

> Column 'Logs.ScanMode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I want to check whether any of the ScanModes are in that list, not some accumulated version of them, so I don't want to pre-aggregate these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Logs` and `SuperLogs` tables have a one-to-many relationship. This means that for each record in `SuperLogs` there can be many records in `Logs`. This is why your query doesn't make sense and can't work as is.
The way I understand the question is this: If Any Log that belongs to the current SuperLog
 have a `ScanMode` that is either one of the values in the list, you want to get 1. If none of them have a `ScanMode` that fits the list, you want to get 0.

If that is correct, a simple solution would be using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name,
CAST
(
    MAX(
        CASE WHEN
        Logs.ScanMode IN
        (
            'Navigational',
            'Locatable',
            'Automatic'
        )
    THEN
        1
    ELSE
        0
    END
    )
    AS BIT
) AS HasLogsWithGpsData
FROM SuperLogs
INNER JOIN Logs ON Logs.SuperLogId = SuperLogs.Id
GROUP BY SuperLogs.Id
```

Comment: `MAX` is just what I needed - I had tried `ANY` and `SOME` to no avail but didn't even think about `MAX` as I was thinking of the result as a boolean value rather than a number.

Comment: Glad to help :-)